# Scheduling callbacks in Web Audio buffers

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm using the Web Audio API to play an MP3 file. I'm unaware of how to schedule events to happen at certain intervals, namely at 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 1 second intervals for quarter notes when using a source buffer (i.e., not creating the sound like certain guides suggest: http://middleearmedia.com/timed-rhythms-with-web-audio-api-and-javascript/).

My context is setup like the following:

```
function setupAudioNodes() {
  javascriptNode = context.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);

  javascriptNode.connect(context.destination);

  analyser = context.createAnalyser();
  analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
  analyser.fftSize = 32; 

  sourceNode = context.createBufferSource();
  sourceNode.connect(analyser);

  analyser.connect(javascriptNode);

  sourceNode.connect(context.destination);
}
```

I can retrieve the current time using `context.currentTime` where context is an audio context, but assigning a callback on that doesn't happen regularly.

I've tried something trivial such as:

```
if ( context.currentTime.toFixed(2).split(".")[1] === .25 ) {
  runFunc();
}
```

However, this doesn't not happen at regular intervals.  If I print out the output it doesn't always print out the same time intervals which means that this approach doesn't appear to work well.

Another approach I've tried is using `setInterval` which I know is far from ideal for lots of reasons but that doesn't work either and will call the function once following the normal interval pace (1 second) and then breaks down into calling it many times.

```
javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() {
    var array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
    setInterval(myFunc(array), 1000);  // first time ok, after it runs many times a second
}
```

My last, somewhat naive approach, is to create a range of acceptable values.  The application I'm working with doesn't need to be extremely precise so I'm hoping I can listen for ranges such as 0.26 - 0.28.  This approach almost works except that it still calls the function several times but several times only every second.

```
if (time >= 0 && time <= 25 ) {
  myFunc(array);
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a checking function very often, for example every 10ms and check if specified time has exceeded. If yes, run the callback and clear the interval:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  if (time >= 25) {
    runFunc();
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}, 10);
```

Comment: One modification I found that made it more accurate was increasing the interval period to 1000 but then adding in a range of values to check for on time.  I will need to find a way to prevent the rare but very possible times when the function is called in quick succession.